# Scala equivalent of new HashSet(Collection)

Tags: java, scala, scala-collections

What is the equivalent Scala constructor (to create an **immutable** `HashSet`) to the Java

```
new HashSet<T>(c)
```

where `c` is of type `Collection<? extends T>`?.

All I can find in the `HashSet` *Object* is `apply`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two parts to the answer.  The first part is that Scala variable argument methods that take a T* are a sugaring over methods taking Seq[T].  You tell Scala to treat a Seq[T] as a list of arguments instead of a single argument using "seq : _*".

The second part is converting a Collection[T] to a Seq[T].  There's no general built in way to do in Scala's standard libraries just yet, but one very easy (if not necessarily efficient) way to do it is by calling toArray.  Here's a complete example.

```
scala> val lst : java.util.Collection[String] = new java.util.ArrayList
lst: java.util.Collection[String] = []

scala> lst add "hello"
res0: Boolean = true

scala> lst add "world"
res1: Boolean = true

scala> Set(lst.toArray : _*)
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[java.lang.Object] = Set(hello, world)
```

Note the scala.Predef.Set and scala.collection.immutable.HashSet are synonyms.

Comment: As it turns out I can't do this because my "inner" collection is actually an instance of java.util.List, not a Scala Seq. I've asked this question as a follow up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674713/converting-java-collection-into-scala-collection

Answer (score 14):

The most concise way to do this is probably to use the `++` operator:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.HashSet
val list = List(1,2,3)
val set = HashSet() ++ list
```

Answer (score 1):

From Scala 2.13 use the companion object

```scala
import scala.collection.immutable.HashSet
val list = List(1,2,3)
val set = HashSet.from(list)
```