# Converting a Java collection into a Scala collection

Tags: java, scala, scala-collections, scala-2.7

Related to Stack Overflow question *[Scala equivalent of new HashSet(Collection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674545)* , how do I convert a Java collection (`java.util.List` say) into a Scala collection `List`?

I am actually trying to convert a Java API call to [Spring's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) `SimpleJdbcTemplate`, which returns a `java.util.List<T>`, into a Scala immutable `HashSet`. So for example:

```
val l: java.util.List[String] = javaApi.query( ... )
val s: HashSet[String] = //make a set from l
```

---

This seems to work. Criticism is welcome!

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Set
import scala.collection.jcl.Buffer 
val s: scala.collection.Set[String] =
                      Set(Buffer(javaApi.query( ... ) ) : _ *)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your last suggestion works, but you can also avoid using `jcl.Buffer`:

```
Set(javaApi.query(...).toArray: _*)
```

Note that `scala.collection.immutable.Set` is made available by default thanks to `Predef.scala`.

Comment: This suggestion doesn't work where I want to keep the type information

Answer (score 128):

For future reference: With Scala 2.8, it could be done like this:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
val list = new java.util.ArrayList[String]()
list.add("test")
val set = list.toSet
```

`set` is a `scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]` after this.

Also see [Ben James' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674713/converting-java-collection-into-scala-collection/6356804#6356804) for a more explicit way (using JavaConverters), which seems to be recommended now.

Comment: Looks like now `JavaConversions` has some implicits making the `toSet` call not necessary.

Comment: @Rajish I think it's better if the conversion is explicit (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301947/what-is-the-difference-between-javaconverters-and-javaconversions-in-scala)

Comment: you are right, its better to use import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

Answer (score 62):

If you want to be more explicit than the JavaConversions demonstrated in [robinst's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674713/converting-java-collection-into-scala-collection/3969631#3969631), you can use JavaConverters:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val l = new java.util.ArrayList[java.lang.String]
val s = l.asScala.toSet
```

Answer (score 25):

*JavaConversions* ([robinst's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674713/converting-java-collection-into-scala-collection/3969631#3969631)) and *JavaConverters* ([Ben James's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674713/converting-java-collection-into-scala-collection/6356804#6356804)) have been deprecated with **Scala 2.10**.

Instead of *JavaConversions* use:

```
import scala.collection.convert.wrapAll._
```

as suggested by [aleksandr_hramcov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22242391/982265).

Instead of *JavaConverters* use:

```
import scala.collection.convert.decorateAll._
```

For both there is also the possibility to only import the conversions/converters to Java or Scala respectively, e.g.:

```
import scala.collection.convert.wrapAsScala._
```

**Update:**
The statement above that *JavaConversions* and *JavaConverters* were deprecated seems to be wrong. There were some deprecated properties in Scala 2.10, which resulted in deprecation warnings when importing them. So the alternate imports here seem to be only aliases. Though I still prefer them, as IMHO the names are more appropriate.

Comment: Why do you say the JavaConversions and JavaConverters are deprecated? In the current documentation 2.11.8 both are not marked as being deprecated and they also do not have a reference to 'decorateAll' or 'wrapAll' stating that is the new and preferred usage.

Comment: @JoostdenBoer Seems there were some deprecated decorators [there](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.10.x/src/library/scala/collection/JavaConverters.scala) in Scala 2.10, though they seem to have been removed again with Scala 2.11.

Answer (score 13):

You may also want to explore this excellent library: [scalaj-collection](http://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-collection) that has two-way conversion between Java and Scala collections. In your case, to convert a java.util.List to Scala List you can do this:

```
val list = new java.util.ArrayList[java.lang.String]
list.add("A")
list.add("B")
list.asScala
```

Comment: That library is the greatest thing ever. Really really works well.

Comment: Revisiting this after couple of years, Scala's JavaConverters is the way to go.

Answer (score 7):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, package [`scala.jdk.CollectionConverters`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/jdk/CollectionConverters$.html) replaces packages `scala.collection.JavaConverters/JavaConversions._`:

```scala
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

// val javaList: java.util.List[String] = java.util.Arrays.asList("one","two","three")
javaList.asScala
// collection.mutable.Buffer[String] = Buffer("one", "two", "three")
javaList.asScala.toSet
// collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set("one", "two", "three")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
val array = java.util.Arrays.asList("one","two","three").toArray

val list = array.toList.map(_.asInstanceOf[String])
```

Comment: this is a great answer and solved my problem. Most of the methods mentioned on the internet just convert the (eg) java.util.List[java.lang.Long] to 
scala.collection.immutable.List[java.lang.Long]. So this method worked for me to convert it to scala.collection.immutable.List[scala.Long]

Answer (score 2):

You can add the type information in the toArray call to make the Set be parameterized:

```
 val s = Set(javaApi.query(....).toArray(new Array[String](0)) : _*)
```

This might be preferable as the collections package is going through a major rework for Scala 2.8 and the scala.collection.jcl package is [going away](http://www.acooke.org/cute/UsingJavaC0.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the Java collection to an array and then create a Scala list from that:

```
val array = java.util.Arrays.asList("one","two","three").toArray
val list = List.fromArray(array)
```

Comment: This isn't great because my java.util.List is coming back out of a Java API as a parametrized list (so my call to the API yields a java.util.List<String>) - I'm trying to turn this into a scala immutable HashSet

Answer (score 1):

Another simple way to solve this problem:

```
import collection.convert.wrapAll._
```