# How to get Scala List from Java List?

Tags: java, scala

I have a Java API that returns a List like:

```
public List<?> getByXPath(String xpathExpr)
```

I am using the below scala code:

```
val lst = node.getByXPath(xpath)
```

Now if I try scala syntax sugar like:

```
lst.foreach{ node => ... }
```

it does not work. I get the error:

```
value foreach is not a member of java.util.List[?0]
```

It seems I need to convert Java List to Scala List. How to do that in above context?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting Java collection into Scala collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674713/converting-java-collection-into-scala-collection)

Comment: @Kim: I'm not sure it's appropriate to close this as a duplicate of that particular question -- that particular question talks about Scala 2.7, and the scala.collection.jcl package doesn't exist anymore in Scala 2.8 and 2.9.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

## EDIT: Note that this is deprecated since 2.12.0. Use `JavaConverters` instead. (comment by @Yaroslav)

Since **Scala 2.8** this conversion is now built into the language using:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

...

lst.toList.foreach{ node =>   .... }
```

works. `asScala` did not work

In 2.12.x use `import scala.collection.JavaConverters._`

In 2.13.x use `import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._`

Comment: On 2.10.4 I had to import scala.collection.JavaConverters._ otherwise I got "value asScala is not a member of java.util.List[String]"

Comment: `JavaConversions` are deprecated since 2.12.0. Use `JavaConverters` instead.

Comment: For 2.13.x, you need `import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._` 
https://scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/jdk/CollectionConverters$.html

Answer (score 98):

There's a handy Scala object just for this - [scala.collection.JavaConverters](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConverters$)

You can do the import and `asScala` afterwards as follows:

```scala
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val lst = node.getByXPath(xpath).asScala
lst.foreach{ node =>   .... }
```

This should give you Scala's `Buffer` representation allowing you to accomplish `foreach`.

Comment: JavaConverters should be preferred over JavaConversions since it makes the conversion explicit (and avoids accidental conversions that may be confusing).  (I.e., this is the correct answer)

Comment: since scala 2.13 this class is deprecated, too. Use scala.jdk.CollectionConverters instead.

Answer (score 10):

I was looking for an answer written in Java and surprisingly couldn't find any clean solutions here. After a while I was able to figure it out so I decided to add it here in case someone else is looking for the Java implementation (I guess it also works in Scala?):

```
JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(myJavaList).toList()
```

Answer (score 10):

If you have to convert a Java `List<ClassA>` to a Scala `List[ClassB]`, then you must do the following:

1) Add

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
```

2) Use methods `asScala`, `toList` and then `map`

```
List <ClassA> javaList = ...
var scalaList[ClassB] = javaList.asScala.toList.map(x => new ClassB(x))
```

3) Add the following to the `ClassB` constructor that receives `ClassA` as a parameter:

```
case class ClassB () {
   def this (classA: ClassA) {
      this (new ClassB (classA.getAttr1, ..., classA.getAttrN))
   }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Shortcut to convert java list to scala list

`import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._`

`myjavaList.asScala.toList`

Comment: `scala.collection.JavaConverters._` is deprecated. Use: `scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._`

Answer (score 6):

Since scala 2.8.1 use `JavaConverters._`
to convert scala and Java collections using asScala and asJava methods.

`import scala.collection.JavaConverters._`

`javalist.asScala`

`scalaSeq.asJava`

see the Conversion relationship [scala doc site](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html)