# What is the difference between JavaConverters and JavaConversions in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-java-interop

In [`scala.collection`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.package), there are two very similar objects [`JavaConversions`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/JavaConversions%24.html) and [`JavaConverters`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/JavaConverters%24.html).

- What is the difference between these two objects?
- Why do they both exist?
- When do I want to use one vs. the other?

Answer (score 265, accepted):

EDIT: `Java Conversions` got `@deprecated` in Scala 2.13.0. Use [scala.jdk.CollectionConverters](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.0/scala/jdk/CollectionConverters$.html) instead.

`JavaConversions` provide a series of implicit methods that convert between a Java collection and the closest corresponding Scala collection, and vice versa. This is done by creating wrappers that implement either the Scala interface and forward the calls to the underlying Java collection, or the Java interface, forwarding the calls to the underlying Scala collection.

`JavaConverters` uses the pimp-my-library pattern to “add” the `asScala` method to the Java collections and the `asJava` method to the Scala collections, which return the appropriate wrappers discussed above. It is newer (since version 2.8.1) than `JavaConversions` (since 2.8) and makes the conversion between Scala and Java collection explicit. Contrary to what David writes in his answer, I'd recommend you make it a habit to use `JavaConverters` as you'll be much less likely to write code that makes a lot of implicit conversions, as you can control the only spot where that will happen: where you write `.asScala` or `.asJava`.

Here's the conversion methods that `JavaConverters` provide:

```
Pimped Type                            | Conversion Method   | Returned Type
=================================================================================================
scala.collection.Iterator              | asJava              | java.util.Iterator
scala.collection.Iterator              | asJavaEnumeration   | java.util.Enumeration
scala.collection.Iterable              | asJava              | java.lang.Iterable
scala.collection.Iterable              | asJavaCollection    | java.util.Collection
scala.collection.mutable.Buffer        | asJava              | java.util.List
scala.collection.mutable.Seq           | asJava              | java.util.List
scala.collection.Seq                   | asJava              | java.util.List
scala.collection.mutable.Set           | asJava              | java.util.Set
scala.collection.Set                   | asJava              | java.util.Set
scala.collection.mutable.Map           | asJava              | java.util.Map
scala.collection.Map                   | asJava              | java.util.Map
scala.collection.mutable.Map           | asJavaDictionary    | java.util.Dictionary
scala.collection.mutable.ConcurrentMap | asJavaConcurrentMap | java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap
—————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
java.util.Iterator                     | asScala             | scala.collection.Iterator
java.util.Enumeration                  | asScala             | scala.collection.Iterator
java.lang.Iterable                     | asScala             | scala.collection.Iterable
java.util.Collection                   | asScala             | scala.collection.Iterable
java.util.List                         | asScala             | scala.collection.mutable.Buffer
java.util.Set                          | asScala             | scala.collection.mutable.Set
java.util.Map                          | asScala             | scala.collection.mutable.Map
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap     | asScala             | scala.collection.mutable.ConcurrentMap
java.util.Dictionary                   | asScala             | scala.collection.mutable.Map
java.util.Properties                   | asScala             | scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]
```

To use the conversions directly from Java, though, you're better off calling methods from `JavaConversions` directly; e.g.:

```
List<String> javaList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
System.out.println(javaList); // [a, b, c]
Buffer<String> scalaBuffer = JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(javaList);
System.out.println(scalaBuffer); // Buffer(a, b, c)
List<String> javaListAgain = JavaConversions.bufferAsJavaList(scalaBuffer);
System.out.println(javaList == javaListAgain); // true
```

Comment: Hi Jean-Philippe. I don't get your point regarding implicits conversion. As you have explained, `ScalaConverter` make use of implicits to add `asJava` and `asScala`. Furthermore, you specify the scala or java type you want to convert to on the new val definition (i.e. `val sl = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]; val jl : java.util.List[Int] = sl`). So using `ScalaConversions` you have an easy way to convert your collection and the ability to fine tune the target type.

Comment: Yes, use JavaConverters over JavaConversions,. But also consider using https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-collection as it has some benefits as converting java.util.List to Seq. (Is the above list from 2.8.1?)

Comment: @David While implicit conversions like those provided by `JavaConversions` are convenient, you may quickly overlook all the places where they can be inserted by the compiler. You control those places with `JavaConverters`. It's the whole discussion about implicit vs explicit conversion.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet implicit conversions in Scala are Scope based so if you don't `import JavaConversions._`, conversions will not occur so you have the control on what is converted. If you place the import the right way (only when needed), you have full control on where the conversion is done.

Comment: @David … and with `JavaConverters` you have the additional safety that nothing happens unless you write it explicitly. That's an additional security, and that's most probably why this class was added.

Comment: You'd think the naming would be better: e.g. something like "JavaConversionsImplicit" and "JavaConversionsExplicit" would have been easier to distinguish.

Comment: Are the JavaConverters usable from within java?  (eg, I have a java.util.List and an API that requires a scala Set and I am writing java code)

Comment: @TheTrav I added an example in Java. I think you're better off using `JavaConversions`, if it's from Java.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think whoever created those classes was stoned. `JavaConversions` is very nice but gives you no way to create immutable scala collections and the `toMap` bits of `JavaConverters` are a PITA to work with.

Answer (score 56):

For anyone landing on this question since Scala 2.12.x, `JavaConversions` is now deprecated and `JavaConverters` is the preferred method.

Comment: Since Scala 2.13, `JavaConverters` is deprecated, and `scala.jdk.CollectionConverters` is the preferred method ;)

Answer (score 8):

In Scala 2.13, `JavaConverters` have been [deprecated](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/7458) in favour of `scala.jdk.CollectionConverters`:

> ...new package `scala.jdk` with objects `CollectionConverters`
>   (classic Java collections, similar to `collection.JavaConverters` in
>   2.12), `StreamConverters`, `FunctionConverters` and `OptionConverters`...

Answer (score 6):

As explained in the API, [`JavaConversions`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/JavaConversions$.html) is a set of implicit conversions that transforms java collections into related scala collection.

You can use it with an `import collection.JavaConversions._`. When necessary, the compiler will automatically transform the java collection into the right scala type.

[`JavaConverters`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html) are a set of decorator that helps transform java or scala collections to scala or java collections using `asScala` or `asJava` methods that will be implicitly added to the collection that you want to transform. In order to use these converters, you need to import :

```
import collection.JavaConverters._
```

You should prefer `JavaConversions` as it's generally easier to use (no need to use `asScala` or `asJava`).

Comment: While using the totally implicit approach of JavaConverters is easier to write, it is harder to read.  Current Scala style suggests that it's better to explicitly call methods to perform conversions, which is why JavaConverters are now preferred.

Comment: JavaConversions are deprecated in Scala 2.12