# Convert scala.collection.immutable.Vector to java.util.Collection

Tags: java, scala, type-conversion, scala-java-interop

How can I make that conversion?

```
var attrDefs = Vector(new AttributeDefinition(), new AttributeDefinition());

request.setAttributeDefinitions(attrDefs);
```

I've read in many different [places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679016/java-scala-collection-conversions-scala-2-10) that we should just import this:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
```

And it should work, but it doesn't compile.

I'm getting this error:

```
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Vector[AttributeDefinition][scalac]
 required: java.util.Collection[AttributeDefinition]
```

I'm using **Scala 2.9.3**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `asJavaCollection` to do the conversion, this should work:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

var attrDefs = Vector(new AttributeDefinition(), new AttributeDefinition())

request.setAttributeDefinitions(attrDefs.asJavaCollection)
```

As an alternative, you can use `import scala.collection.JavaConversions._` to not have to call `asJavaCollection`. However, I find that it makes what the code is doing more readable to call the method. Here's the alternate example:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

var attrDefs = Vector(new AttributeDefinition(), new AttributeDefinition())

request.setAttributeDefinitions(attrDefs)
```

Comment: awesome @Noah! I'm having so many issues with my Scala plugin for Eclipse. Actually, it is still showing me that the method does not exist, but it works!

Comment: I'm not sure how attached you are to Eclipse but I find that Intellij is far better at most things, including Scala :)

Comment: A lot of people in my team are using Intellij already, I think Scala will force me to migrate :O)

Answer (score 1):

As of Scala 2.9, you should prefer covert package for converting Java <-> Scala collections:

```
val attr = new java.util.Vector[String]()
scala.collection.convert.wrapAsScala.collectionAsScalaIterable(attr) // it's implicit
```

so import wrapAsScala:

```
import collection.convert.wrapAsScala._
var attrDefs = Vector(new AttributeDefinition(), new AttributeDefinition())
request.setAttributeDefinitions(attrDefs)
```