# How to iterate a list of Pair with Scala?

Tags: list, scala, loops

I want to iterate a list of `Pair` objects, but have a few problems. As following variable:

```
val list: JList[Pair[Integer, Integer]]
for (pair <- list){
    //how to get first value and second value of pair instance
}
```

When I use `for` with `<-` to iterate, I can't get `Pair` instance and can't get properties of `Pair`.

Comment: I think you need add more context, such as what is the `JList`, and what does the `indexCols` mean?

Comment: It's usually a good idea to post everything needed to compile your code.  This is especially true if we need to `import` something.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming `JList` here is the java swing component. If that is the case, then you cannot so far as I know use it directly in a for-comprehension. Instead you'll need to do something like:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

for (pair <- list.getSelectedValuesList) {
  //do something with pair 
}
```

The import pulls in implicits that will convert from Java collections to Scala collections. You'll need this because the for-comprehension you're using is de-sugared to a `foreach` method call, and `java.util.List` does not define a `foreach` method.

Answer (score 0):

Incrementing Jason's answer. It is usually recommended to use `JavaConverters` instead of `JavaConversions` to avoid [nasty issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20817294/1706351). It is a little bit more verbose, but safer.

The solution would be something like this:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

for (pair <- list.asScala.getSelectedValuesList) {
  //do something with pair 
}
```