# How to convert a java.util.List to a Scala list

Tags: list, scala, scala-java-interop

I have this Scala method with below error. Cannot convert into a Scala list.

```
 def findAllQuestion():List[Question]={
   questionDao.getAllQuestions()
 }
```

type mismatch; found : `java.util.List[com.aitrich.learnware.model.domain.entity.Question]` required: 
 `scala.collection.immutable.List[com.aitrich.learnware.model.domain.entity.Question]`

Comment: Folks looking at this question might find this other question of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301947/what-is-the-difference-between-javaconverters-and-javaconversions-in-scala

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
```

will do implicit conversion for you; e.g.:

```
var list = new java.util.ArrayList[Int](1,2,3)
list.foreach{println}
```

Comment: `scala.collection.JavaConversions._` is deprecated in favor of `scala.collection.JavaConverters._` so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16164163/918858) is better

Comment: JavaConverts has been deprecated in favor of:
`scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._` as of 2.13. Details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55408424/63013).

Answer (score 142):

You can simply convert the List using Scala's `JavaConverters`:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

def findAllQuestion():List[Question] = {
  questionDao.getAllQuestions().asScala.toList
}
```

Comment: This seems working..
def findAllStudentTest(): List[StudentTest] = {
    var list = studentTestDao.getAllStudentTests()
    var slist = list.asScala.toList
    slist
  }

Comment: a java.util.List .asScala comes back as a buffer for me oddly.

Comment: Me too:  
`    scala> import scala.collection.JavaConverters._  `
    import scala.collection.JavaConverters._  
    
    scala> val l = new java.util.ArrayList[java.lang.String]
    l: java.util.ArrayList[String] = []
    
    scala>  l.add("hi")
    res70: Boolean = true
    
    scala> l.add("de")
    res71: Boolean = true
    
    scala> l.asScala
    res72: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[String] = Buffer(hi, de)`

Comment: a scala `Buffer` is a java `List`. Everything is fine :)

Comment: @mauhiz If a Scala `Buffer` is a Java `List`, then *nothing* is fine! The OP wanted a conversion from Java List to an immutable Scala List. Expressions that expect a Scala `List` won't typecheck with a `Buffer`.

Comment: you forgot to add `.toList`  so the code is `questionDao.getAllQuestions().asScala.toList`

Comment: Just write `asScala.toList` and it will convert to Scala list

Answer (score 32):

```
def findAllStudentTest(): List[StudentTest] = { 
  studentTestDao.getAllStudentTests().asScala.toList
}
```

Comment: Why the `var`s? Also, it seems that the last two lines could be combined to a single line `list.asScala.toList`

Comment: the first var list will get java util list
and the second slist will convert java util list to scala list.

Comment: I mean, why `var` instead of `val` if you're not modifying the variable

Comment: But in the case sub operations ,wee need to use var instead of val.

Comment: Both the `var list` and `val slist` were unnecessary. I think they made this answer more complicated, so I consolidated them and made the answer more simple. @jijeshvu07 If you disagree, I would be happy to undo the edit and submit this change instead as its own answer.

Comment: The `.asScala` did not seem to be recognized any more (Scala 2.12). Just `.toList` or `.toSeq` is enough.

Answer (score 22):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, the package `scala.collection.JavaConverters` is marked as deprecated in favor of [`scala.jdk.CollectionConverters`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/jdk/CollectionConverters$.html):

```
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

// val javaList: java.util.List[Int] = java.util.Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)
javaList.asScala.toList
// List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 8):

Import `JavaConverters` , the response of @fynn was missing `toList`

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

def findAllQuestion():List[Question] = {
  //           java.util.List -> Buffer -> List
  questionDao.getAllQuestions().asScala.toList
}
```