# Type mismatch found java.util.List[String]:required List[String]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-java-interop

I am very new to scala. I have started using scala for my spark project. I am using some of java code. following line I am getting error.

```
         case class docDisplay( id :String,name :String,  session :String,
  time :String, docguid: scala.collection.immutable.List[String]
```

)

Code for my ParseDocumentGuid which is the java class is as follow.

```
public static List<String> ParseGuid(String Data, String type,String Name) {    
    boolean validJson=checkValidJson(Data);
    if(validJson==true)

    {
        try
        {
            JSONObject  json = null;
         json = new JSONObject (Data);
        List<String> singleDocGuidList= new ArrayList<String>();
        if(json!=null && json.getString("guid").equalsIgnoreCase("guid") )
        {
                    singleDocGuidList.add(json.getString("guid"));
        }
         return singleDocGuidList;
    }    
    catch(Exception e)
       {
           List<String> singleDocGuidList= new ArrayList<String>();
            singleDocGuidList.add(e.getMessage());
            return singleDocGuidList;
       }
    }
 else
    {
        List<String> singleDocGuidList= new ArrayList<String>();
        singleDocGuidList.add("unKnownDocumentGuid");
        return singleDocGuidList;
    }
}
```

Here is the code which is calling above method

```
def selectColumnsPerDocdisplayRows(row:Row):List[String]= {
    docDisplay(
        row.getAs[String]("id"),
        row.getAs[String]("name"),
        row.getAs[String]("session"),
        row.getAs[String]("time"),
    Utils.ParseDocumentGuid(row.getAs("Data"),Utils.DOCDISRELATED,row.getAs[String]("name"))
        );
}
```

So I am getting error on my method def selectColumnsPerDocdisplayRows() saying

**type mismatch;  found   : java.util.List[String]  required: List[String]**

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162090/how-to-convert-a-java-util-list-to-a-scala-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello Thank you Brian Kent and Chris Shain for suggesion, I have removed List[String] from my def and it worked with

import collection.JavaConverters._

and .asScala.toList

```
 def selectColumnsPerDocdisplayRows(row:Row)= {
docDisplay(
    row.getAs[String]("id"),
    row.getAs[String]("name"),
    row.getAs[String]("session"),
    row.getAs[String]("time"),
Utils.ParseDocumentGuid(row.getAs("Data"),Utils.DOCDISRELATED,row.getAs[String]("name")).asScala.toList
    );
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Add the conversions:

```
import collection.JavaConverters._
```

and add `.asScala` to convert

Comment: import collection.JavaConverters._  
   def selectColumnsPerDocdisplayRows(row:Row):List[String]= {
  docDisplay(
   row.getAs[String]("id"),
   row.getAs[String]("name"),
   row.getAs[String]("session"),
   row.getAs[String]("time"),
     QSUtils.ParseDocumentGuid(row.getAs("Data"),QSUtils.DOCDISRELATED,row.getAs[String]("name")).asScala
   );
 }   I got following error

Comment: `.asScala.toList`

Comment: tried .asScala.toList got following message       
type mismatch;  found   : com.extract.spark.QSSparkUtils.docDisplay  required: List[String]

Comment: Thanks it worked, I had to remove return type List[String] from my def .

Comment: import collection.JavaConverters._  
   def selectColumnsPerDocdisplayRows(row:Row)= {
  docDisplay(
   row.getAs[String]("id"),
   row.getAs[String]("name"),
   row.getAs[String]("session"),
   row.getAs[String]("time"),
     Utils.ParseDocumentGuid(row.getAs("Data"),Utils.DOCDISRELATED,row.getAs[String]("name")).asScala.toList
   );
 }  ---->Thank you.