# Access ArrayList outside nested If else block in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, arraylist, apache-spark-sql

I have following code :-

```
 var ArrayStop = new ArrayList[imeistoppage]()
 val listings = rddStopCalculate.zipWithIndex().map(p => {
        if (p._2 == 0) {
          imei = p._1.imei
          lat = p._1.latitude
          long = p._1.longitude
          gpsdt = p._1.gpsdt
        } else if (p._2 > 0 && p._2 != lastindex) {
          if (p._1.imei.equals(imei) && p._1.latitude == lat && p._1.longitude == long) {
            flag += 1
            newgpsdt = p._1.gpsdt
          } else {
            if (flag > 0) {
              timeDiff = newgpsdt.getTime() - gpsdt.getTime()
              if (timeDiff > 60000) {
                ArrayStop.add(imeistoppage(p._1.imei, lat, long, timeDiff))
              }
              flag = 0
            }
            imei = p._1.imei
            lat = p._1.latitude
            long = p._1.longitude
            gpsdt = p._1.gpsdt
          }
        } else {
          if (p._1.imei.equals(imei) && p._1.latitude == lat && p._1.longitude == long) {
            flag += 1
            newgpsdt = p._1.gpsdt
          }
          if (flag > 0) {
            timeDiff = newgpsdt.getTime() - gpsdt.getTime()
            if (timeDiff > 60000) {
              ArrayStop.add(imeistoppage(p._1.imei, lat, long, timeDiff))
            }
            flag = 0
          }
        }
        ArrayStop
      }).collect()

      val returnList = listings(listings.length - 1)
      val tempCollection = returnList.asScala
      val tempRDD = sc.parallelize(tempCollection)
      tempRDD.saveToCassandra("db", "table", SomeColumns("imei", "lat", "long", "duration"))
```

As we can see in above code I'm actually adding data to ArrayStop for specific IF condition only and I want this to be accessed outside this rdd loop but I was unable to do so So I created a variable "listings" to store data which is actually taking all the rows whereas I want only those entries which are added in ArrayStop. So what is the best way to bring any array outside nested If-else block. This is different from this issue 
    [Scala spark, listbuffer is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40699432/scala-spark-listbuffer-is-empty)
Thanks,

Comment: why don't you create ArrayStop inside map function itself ?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan - If I'll create ArrayStop inside map function will I be able to access its content outside ? and how exactly will help it me if I create ArrayStop inside ?

Comment: inside map function but outside if else statement. try it and see it yourself.

Comment: I tried but now it is considering separate array for each if block like I have three part in this "IF" as you can see I'm using add inside [else if (2nd part) (p._2 > 0 && p._2 != lastindex) {ArrayStop.add(imeistoppage(p._1.imei, lat, long, timeDiff))}] and last else block (3rd part). So now when I tried printing I got only array of last else block(3rd part) and not from above else if block i.e. 2nd part. Where I'm going wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala spark, listbuffer is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40699432/scala-spark-listbuffer-is-empty)

Comment: Take a look on `flatMap()` instead of `map()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350722/what-is-the-difference-between-map-and-flatmap-and-a-good-use-case-for-each) is the difference and [`accumulators`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#accumulators). Both these things can help you achieve what you want.

Comment: @VladislavVarslavans - this gives me an error type mismatch; found : java.util.ArrayList[imeistoppage] required: TraversableOnce[?]

Comment: @user9613318 - my issue is somewhat different, I can relate to it but its different like I'm stuck inside nested If Else block and your mentioned link gives simple single block .. are you getting ?

Comment: @Pinnacle. This is because `ArrayList` is java type, but in `flatMap()` is required scala type `TraversableOnce[T]`. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162090/how-to-convert-a-java-util-list-to-a-scala-list) question to see how to convert java type to scala type. You can either convert your ArrayList to scala List, or just use scala List instead of ArrayList from start.

Comment: Ok this resolved my issue. Can you please provide this comment as solution so that I can accept your answer and close the issue. Thanks,