# Scala type disagreement between compiler and run-time?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

Converting from `java.util.ArrayList` to `scala.collection.immutable.List`, the 2.10 compiler and run-time may seem to be in disagreement, about the type of `val emits`:

```
import org.ahocorasick.trie._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._    // convert Java colllections to Scala ones

object wierd {

  val trie = new Trie

  def trieInit(patterns: List[String]) {
    trie.onlyWholeWords();
    for (pattern <- patterns)
      trie.addKeyword(pattern)
  }

  def patternTest(text : String) : List[String] = 
  {
    val emitsJ = trie.parseText(text)
    val emits = emitsJ.asScala map (i => i.getKeyword)

    println(s"converted from ${emitsJ.getClass} to ${emits.getClass}")

    //return(emits)
    return (List.empty[String])
  }

  trieInit(List("hello"))
  patternTest("hello")
}
```

Yields:

`converted from class java.util.ArrayList to class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon`

Now changing to return the real value by changing only the `return` line -

```
import org.ahocorasick.trie._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._    // convert Java colllections to Scala ones

object wierd {

  val trie = new Trie

  def trieInit(patterns: List[String]) {
    trie.onlyWholeWords();
    for (pattern <- patterns)
      trie.addKeyword(pattern)
  }

  def patternTest(text : String) : List[String] = 
  {
    val emitsJ = trie.parseText(text)
    val emits = emitsJ.asScala map (i => i.getKeyword)

    println(s"converted from ${emitsJ.getClass} to ${emits.getClass}")

    return(emits)
    //return (List.empty[String])
  }

  trieInit(List("hello"))
  patternTest("hello")
}
```

Yields a compilation error:

```
[error] reproduce.scala:23: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Iterable[String]
[error]  required: List[String]
[error]     return(emits)
[error]            ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

What would be the simple explanation for this?
How would I better approach the conversion?

Answer (score 1):

JavaConverters convert to the Scala collection closest to the Java collection that it has pimped.  You still have to call toList to further transform it to the collection you want:

```
val emits = emitsJ.asScala.toList map (i => i.getKeyword)
```

See related: [What is the difference between JavaConverters and JavaConversions in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301947/what-is-the-difference-between-javaconverters-and-javaconversions-in-scala)

Answer (score 1):

the return type of `trie.parseText` is declared as `java.util.Collection[Emit]`. This isn't very specific, there are lots of possible subtypes of `Collection`, they aren't specifying what specific type they are going to return, it could be a `TreeSet`, it could be a `Vector`, it could be an `ArrayList`. But as far as the compiler is concerned, it could be anything which is a sub-type of `Collection`.  You have inspected it at run-time and seen that for some particular input, it happened to return an `ArrayList`, but there is no way the compiler could know this.

When you call .asScala on this, you are using this implicit definition from `JavaConverters`

```
implicit def iterableAsScalaIterableConverter[A](i: java.lang.Iterable[A]): convert.Decorators.AsScala[Iterable[A]]
```

Which converts a java.lang.Itaerable into a scala.collection.Iterable.

There is no converter for `Collection` so you get a converter for the next most specific thing, `Iterable`.  you call map on this `Iterable` and get an `Iterable` back.

Now, just like you have inspected the runtime value of the `Collection` returned from parseText and seen that it was a `ArrayList` you have inspected the value returned from this map operation and have seen that it is a `scala.collection.immutable.List`, but again, the compiler can't know this, all that it can know is that you gotten something which is a subclass of `Iterable` back.

Simply calling .toList on the resulting `Iterable` should be all you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

So what's happening here is that the underlying object returned to you from `asScala` is a `List` but it's been downcast to an `Iterable` since `List <: Iterable` this is all fine until you want to use the `Iterable` as a list. The easiest option is to call `toList` on it.

For a little more detail you can browse the [source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src%2Flibrary%2Fscala%2Fcollection%2Fconvert%2FWrappers.scala#L58):

```
  case class JCollectionWrapper[A](underlying: ju.Collection[A]) extends AbstractIterable[A] with Iterable[A] {
    def iterator = underlying.iterator
    override def size = underlying.size
    override def isEmpty = underlying.isEmpty
    def newBuilder[B] = new mutable.ArrayBuffer[B]
  }
```

So your call to `asScala` gives you back this wrapper. Next, your call to map is using [this](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src%2Flibrary%2Fscala%2Fcollection%2FSeq.scala#L35) `CanBuildFrom` which is then used in [this map operation](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src%2Flibrary%2Fscala%2Fcollection%2FTraversableLike.scala#L238), which finally gives you the result which happens to be a `List` because the builder is a [`ListBuffer`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src%2Flibrary%2Fscala%2Fcollection%2Fimmutable%2FSeq.scala#L46) and the `result` is a `List`, which again happens to be an `Iterable` because the can build from pattern downcasts to `Iterable`. Hope that explains everything :)

Comment: Thanks @Noah! Can you help me further connect the dots - where exactly in all this is the downcast (first) happening?

Comment: @matt The downcast happens at the start, the object that `asScala` returns is downcast to `Iterable` as you don't get back a type of `JCollectionWrapper`. From their the `CanBuildFrom` pattern preserves the type passed to it, so it keeps `Iterable` instead of changing to `List` even though that's what you're getting.