# Convert a Java List of Lists to Scala without O(n) iteration?

Tags: list, scala, scala-collections

Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674713/converting-a-java-collection-into-a-scala-collection) do a good job of explaining how to use Scala's Java Converters to change a Java List into a Scala List. Unfortunately, I need to convert a List of Lists from Java to Scala types, and that solution doesn't work:

```
// pseudocode
java.util.List[java.util.List[String]].asScala
  -> scala.collection.immutable.List[java.util.List[String]]
```

Is there a way to do this conversion without an O(N) iteration over the Java object?

Comment: Probably it would be possible with (Indexed)Seq, but the immutable.List is a concrete type, so it is not, you have to pay the price in advance (where N is the size of the outer list).

Comment: Are you sure you need to avoid it? Have you tried `jlistOfjList.asScala.map(_.asScala)`?

Comment: @Cory, so you were just kidding about needing it to be under O(n)?

Comment: @dhg I definitely should have phrased my question more accurately. What I was wanting to avoid was an ugly `foreach` or iteration, as I'm used to coming from Java and C++. I wasn't even aware something as elegant as `jlistOfjList.asScala.map(_.asScala)` was even possible in Scala. I should have said I wanted an *elegant* solution, not one that avoids O(N) iteration. In short, no, I was not kidding, I just misexpressed my intentions.

Comment: @CoryKlein Learn to use map. It's (imo) the basic building block that distinguishes functional programming from other styles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the nested lists as well, but that would require the up front O(n):

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val javaListOfLists = List(List("a", "b", "c").asJava, List("d", "e", "f").asJava).asJava
val scalaListOfLists = javaListOfLists.asScala.toList.map(_.asScala.toList)
```

Alternatively, you could convert the outer list into a Stream[List[T]], that would only apply the conversion cost as you accessed each item

```
val scalaStreamOfLists = javaListOfLists.asScala.toStream.map(_.asScala.toList)
```

If you don't want to pay the conversion cost at all, you could write a wrapper around java.util.List which would give you a scala collection interface. a rought shot at that would be:

```
def wrap[T](javaIterator: java.util.Iterator[T]): Stream[T] = {
  if (javaIterator.hasNext)
    javaIterator.next #:: wrap(javaIterator)
  else
    empty
}

val outerWrap = wrap(javaListOfLists.iterator).map(inner => wrap(inner.iterator()))
```

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you can use [scalaj-collection](https://github.com/jozic/scalaj) library i wrote specifically for this purpose

```
import com.daodecode.scalaj.collection._

val listOfLists: java.util.List[java.util.List[String]] = ...
val s: mutable.Seq[mutable.Seq[String]] = listOfLists.deepAsScala
```

that's it. It will convert all nested java collections and primitive types to scala versions. You can also convert directly to immutable data structures using `deepAsScalaImmutable` (with some copying overhead of course)