# Converting a Java Collection<E> to a Scala Collection?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a Java class implementing: `Iterable< Element>, Collection< Element>, List< Element>`

How do I turn it into a Scala Iterator or List or any other Scala collection, so I can do something like `map` or `el(2)`?

Comment: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html (also check the discussion below that)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a Java collection into a Scala collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674713/converting-a-java-collection-into-a-scala-collection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `JavaConverters`:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val yourJavaList = // ...
val scalaList = yourJavaList.asScala
```