# Convert Java List to Scala Seq

Tags: java, scala, seq, scala-java-interop

I need to implement a method that returns a Scala `Seq`, in Java.

But I encounter this error:

```
java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to scala.collection.Seq
```

Here is my code so far:

```
@Override
public Seq<String> columnNames() {
    List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
    a.add("john");
    a.add("mary");
    Seq<String> b = (scala.collection.Seq<String>) a;
    return b;
}
```

But `scala.collection.JavaConverters` doesn't seem to offer the possibility to convert as a `Seq`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a Java collection into a Scala collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674713/converting-a-java-collection-into-a-scala-collection)

Comment: You're asking for trouble if you try to do anything with Scala collections in Java. Write a bit of Scala code which does the conversion using scala.collection.JavaConverters.

Comment: @TzachZohar most of the answer are done is scala. My code is Java, it's part of a huge program, I can't externalize this treatment...

Comment: As @LuigiPlinge mentioned this is not a good idea! You'll probably have a lot of problems trying to invoke method on this sequence, god forbid you try invoking anything that requires implicits

Comment: "they can result in unexpected behavior and performance" in the docs doesn't sound very convincing ... especially, since the very next sentence suggests `JavaConverters` that "offer the _same_ conversions". :)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

JavaConverters is what I needed to solve this.

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters;

public Seq<String> convertListToSeq(List<String> inputList) {
    return JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(inputList.iterator()).asScala().toSeq();
}
```

Comment: Slightly shorter version: `JavaConverters.asScalaIterableConverter(a).asScala().toSeq();`

Comment: `JavaConverters.collectionAsScalaIterableConverter(list).asScala().toSeq()` was the proper approach for me with Scala 2.12.6. There is also a `JavaConverters.iterableAsScalaIterableConverter` method if the source is an iterable instead of a collection.

Comment: asScalaIteratorConverter
(java.util.Iterator<A>)
in JavaConverters cannot be applied
to
(scala.collection.Iterator<java.lang.String>)
 
 reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) A exist so that Iterator<String> conforms to Iterator<A

Answer (score 24):

`JavaConversions` should work. I think, you are looking for something like this: `JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(a).toSeq()`

Comment: `JavaConversions` is deprecated and now it should be written as `JavaConverters.asScalaBuffer(a)`

Comment: _Should_ be? Nah ... Recommended by some unknown person who thought it was a better idea is more like it :)

Comment: Probably. I just followed the hint in the Scala API. I do not know either of the persons who was writing and/or deprecating it ;-)

Answer (score 17):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, package [`scala.jdk.javaapi.CollectionConverters`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/jdk/javaapi/CollectionConverters$.html) replaces deprecated packages `scala.collection.JavaConverters/JavaConversions`:

```java
import scala.jdk.javaapi.CollectionConverters;

// List<String> javaList = Arrays.asList("a", "b");
CollectionConverters.asScala(javaList).toSeq();
// Seq[String] = List(a, b)
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me! (Java 8, Spark 2.0.0)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import scala.collection.JavaConverters;
import scala.collection.Seq;

public class Java2Scala
{

    public Seq<String> getSeqString(ArrayList<String> list)
        {
            return JavaConverters.asScalaIterableConverter(list).asScala().toSeq();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

@[Fundhor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4708077/fundhor), the method `asScalaIterableConverter` was not showing up in the IDE. It may be due to a difference in the versions of Scala. I am using Scala 2.11. Instead, it showed up `asScalaIteratorConverter`. I made a slight change to your final snippet and it worked fine for me.
`scala.collection.JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(columnNames.iterator()).asScala().toSeq()` where `columnNames` is a `java.util.List`.

thanks !

Answer (score 5):

Up to 4 elements, you can simply use the factory method of the Seq class like this :

```
Seq<String> seq1 =  new Set.Set1<>("s1").toSeq();
Seq<String> seq2 =  new Set.Set2<>("s1", "s2").toSeq();
Seq<String> seq3 =  new Set.Set3<>("s1", "s2", "s3").toSeq();
Seq<String> seq4 =  new Set.Set4<>("s1", "s2", "s3", "s4").toSeq();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters;
import scala.collection.Seq;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Helpers {
    public Seq<String> convertListToSeq(ArrayList<String> inputList) {
        return JavaConverters.collectionAsScalaIterableConverter(inputList).asScala().toSeq();
    }
}
```

Versions -

```
compile 'org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.3.1'
compile 'org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.3.1'
compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.11:2.8.8"
```