# Spark-Java : How to add an array column in spark Dataframe

Tags: java, arrays, list, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to add a new column to my Spark Dataframe. New column added will be of a size based on a variable (say `salt`) post which I will use that column to explode the dataset to use in salted join.

Currently, I am using consecutive `lit` in an `array` function but that has a problem that it cannot be parameterized and looks worst as a coding practice. My current implementation looks something like below.

```
int salt =3;

Dataset<Row> Reference_with_Salt_Col = Reference.withColumn("salt_array", array(lit(0), lit(1), lit(2)));
```

I have referred and looked at various methods but none of them seems to solve the problem in Java.
`functions.typedlit` approach though works in Python/Scala doesn't seem to work in Java. Further passing an array or list also doesn't help with spark giving the error on the same.

I am using Spark 2.2.0 and Java 1.8 versions

Comment: Try converting the java list to scala seq before calling typedlit. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988315/convert-java-list-to-scala-seq)

Comment: Hi mck, Did try this but was not able to achieve it. Might be due to some scala version mismatch.
Was able to use the map implementation. Although below one from @blackbishop is straight forward implementation that does seem to do the worl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array` function, but first convert each element of the list into `lit`. Example by using `map` function on stream:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.*;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

// example of input dataframe
Reference.show();

//+-----+
//|label|
//+-----+
//|    a|
//|    b|
//|    c|
//+-----+

List<Integer> salt_array = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2);

Reference.withColumn(
        "salt_array",
        functions.array(salt_array.stream().map(functions::lit).toArray(Column[]::new))
).show();

//+-----+----------+
//|label|salt_array|
//+-----+----------+
//|    a| [0, 1, 2]|
//|    b| [0, 1, 2]|
//|    c| [0, 1, 2]|
//+-----+----------+
```

To generate an array that holds a range stating from 0 to `salt - 1`, you can use `IntStream.rangeClosed` like this:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

int salt = 3;

Dataset<Row> Reference_with_Salt_Col = Reference.withColumn(
        "salt_array",
        functions.array(IntStream.rangeClosed(0, salt - 1).mapToObj(functions::lit).toArray(Column[]::new))
);
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for. 
Was able to achieve a messed up implementation using map but your is way cleaner.