# Convert java.util.ArrayList to Seq in Scala

Tags: scala

I have the following structure in Scala:

```
import java.util.ArrayList
val array = new ArrayList[ArrayList[String]]

// ... add values to array
```

Now, I need to convert it to `Seq[Seq[String]]`, how can this be achieved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a Java collection into a Scala collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674713/converting-a-java-collection-into-a-scala-collection)

Comment: Specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3969631/2288659) would seem to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but in that answer the list has one dimension, and in my question it has two. Also, it's from 2010, probably changed by now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following,

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
val array = new ArrayList[ArrayList[String]]
val seq: Seq[Seq[String]] = array.map(_.toSeq)
...
```

Let me know if this helps, Cheers.

Comment: thanks, I had to do `val seq = array.map(_.toSeq).toSeq`

Comment: @peterSc the second `.toSeq` is a redundant collection conversion, so removed it. `seq` has a `Seq` type.Do mark it as accepted if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

A second solution using explicit conversions:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import java.util.ArrayList

val array = new ArrayList[ArrayList[String]]

// Mutable, default conversion for java.util.ArrayList
val mutableSeq : Seq[Seq[String]] = array.asScala.map( _.asScala)

// Immutable, using toList on mutable conversion result
val immutableSeq : Seq[Seq[String]] = array.asScala.toList.map( _.asScala.toList)
```

To clarify the difference between Java JavaConverters and JavaConversions please read:

[What is the difference between JavaConverters and JavaConversions in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301947/what-is-the-difference-between-javaconverters-and-javaconversions-in-scala)

Answer (score 0):

The `scala.collection.JavaConverters._`  is depricated.
The latest ways is:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

val a = asScalaBuffer(array)
```

Now you can convert a to any of the collections

```
to        toBuffer       toIterable   toList   toParArray   toSet      toString        toVector
toArray   toIndexedSeq   toIterator   toMap    toSeq        toStream   toTraversable
```

like this

```
val b = a.toSeq
```

[Here](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-go-from-java-collections-convert-in-scala-interact/) is a complete tutorial

Comment: `JavaConversions is not a member of package collection`

Comment: seems like it is a member now, I checked on Scala 2.11.12

Comment: 2.11.12? That's far, far,  from _"the latest way."_